# How can I pay NHS surcharges for children born in the UK?

Tags: uk-visa, health-insurance

I have been in the UK on a Tier 2 visa since April 2015. How can I pay NHS surcharges for my children who were born in the UK? My children have never travelled outside of the UK, so I haven't applied for visas for them as my dependents.

Next month, I am applying for an extension to my visa. Do I need to apply for their Tier 2 visas as dependent family members, or can I apply after I am granted Indefinite Leave to Remain (ILR)?

Comment: You should investigate what papers they need at the same time that you deal with the NHS requirements. As you can see from the newspapers today in England, it is important to maintain your own and your children's records and immigration status.

Comment: Like your kids could live in the UK for the next 50 years, and then the government decides that some statistics need cleaning up.